# Granule minification and merging in clustered environment

Tags: javascript, css, yui, minify

I am currently using Granule to minify and merge my CSS/JS files. It works fine on my local environment but I am encountering problems on clustered environments.

As Granule works during runtime, each node of the cluster computes its own file, therefore problems can occur when a user loads a page from one node of the cluster and his browser tries to load the resources from another node of the cluster. The other node doesn't necessarily have it.

It isn't possible to use sticky sessions in our case because our resources are fetched from another domain (for cache purposes).

Can Granule be used for my problem or should I switch to YUI Compressor? (would generate the files during the build, so they would be the same for all nodes of the cluster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible maintained replacements include:

- [Jawr](http://jawr.java.net)
- [Wro4j](https://github.com/wro4j/wro4j)
- [WUIC](http://wuic.github.io)

Answer (score 0):

Already heard about this issue when bundle are generated at runtime. You should fallback to build time approach if you use granule in a clustered environment.

Comment: Can Granule be used during build time? Or should I switch to YUI Compressor?

Comment: Yes granule can be used at build time. BTW you should consider a more active project like JAWR or WUIC to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I also used granule in one project and I was very happy with how it worked - until i moved from my development machine to (demo) production server and did intensive testing. The performance of the server (Apache/Tomcat) slowed down and therefore I had to abandon it. It might well be, that there were ways to optimize the runtime, but I just didn't find the time for it...